# How can I delete a document with Next.JS/Mongodb using next-connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

I'm building my first CRUD app with NextJS/Mongodb and I'm using next-connect for the methods and I'm super new to all this.

I was able to successfully create a post, and update user profiles but I am completely stuck on deleting posts. I've tried to mimic the way I created posts but instead switch it to `.deleteOne` instead of `.insertOne`. I can also display `post._id` so I know that I can access it. I'm just confused on how to pass it into my delete function.

I understand that I should be passing in the `post._id` and then sending that to the `handler.delete` which lives in the `api/` folder for NextJS then calling my delete function within the `handler.delete`. I've gone through multiple examples of using next-connect for CRUD operations but almost none of them demonstrate the `delete` operation. Or maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place. I've attached the code below for reference on where I currently am.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
// components/post/posts.jsx

function Post({ post }) {

  const postDelete = (id) => {
    const body = {
      _id: id,
    };
    fetch("/api/posts", {
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
        {post._id}
        <button onClick={() => postDelete(post._id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
);
```

```
// api/posts/index.js

handler.delete(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("reached handler delete function");
  const deleteResult = await deletePost(req.db, {
    _id: req.post._id,
  });
  return res.json({ deleteResult });
});
```

```
// db/posts.js

export async function deletePost(db, { _id }) {
  return db.collection("posts").deleteOne({
    _id,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
// api/posts/index.js

handler.delete(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("reached handler delete function");
  const deleteResult = await deletePost(req.db, {
    _id: req.post._id,
  });
  return res.json({ deleteResult });
});
```

by

```
// api/posts/index.js

handler.delete(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("reached handler delete function");
  const deleteResult = await deletePost(req.db, req.body._id);
  return res.json({ deleteResult });
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work. I added a console log to the handler function and clicking the button prints the console log but does not do anything else unfortunately.

Comment: if your project is not private, send a sandbox or a link to a repo so I can check it.

Comment: I figured out the issue :). I'll add an answer below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

The issue was my variable names.

```
// components/post/posts.jsx

const postDelete = async (event) => {
    if (userInfo) {
      const body = {
        postId: post._id,
      };
      const res = await fetch("/api/posts/patch", {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      if (res.status === 200) {
        toast.success("Post Deleted!");
      }
    } else {
      toast.error("Please sign-in!");
    }
  };
```

```
// api/posts/index.js

handler.delete(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const del = await deletePost(req.db, {
    postId: req.body.postId,
  });
  return res.status(200).send("Uploaded");
});
```

```
// db/posts.js

export async function deletePost(db, { postId }) {
  return db
    .collection("posts")
    .deleteOne({
      "_id": postId,
    })
    .then(({ value }) => value);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the question. I'm new to next.js and also confused about delete function... I'm looking through your example and I don't understand db/posts.js part... Is is models for database? but in my models there is only schema< I understand you cannot post there any script? There should be only schema? At least that's what I have in the file so far...